# Rewrite some C# generic code into F#

Tags: c#, generics, f#

I'm trying to rewrite generic code like this (C#):

```
U Upcast<T, U>(T x) where T : U { return x; }
```

In F#:

```
let ucast<'T, 'U when 'T :> 'U> (x: 'T) = x :> 'U
```

But F# constraint solving works different than C# and compiler outputs a bunch of typing errors:

> **error FS0698:** Invalid constraint: the
>   type used for the constraint is
>   sealed, which means the constraint
>   could only be satisfied by at most one
>   solution
>
> **warning FS0064:** This construct causes
>   code to be less generic than indicated
>   by the type annotations. The type
>   variable 'T has been constrained to be
>   type ''U'.
>
> **error FS0663:** This type parameter has
>   been used in a way that constrains it
>   to always be ''U'
>
> **error FS0013:** The static coercion from
>   type     'U     to      'U
>   involves an indeterminate type based
>   on information prior to this program
>   point. Static coercions are not
>   allowed on some types. Further type
>   annotations are needed.
>
> **error FS0661:** One or more of the
>   explicit class or function type
>   variables for this binding could not
>   be generalized, because they were
>   constrained to other types

Please, explain me how to correctly rewrite C# code above and why F# version I've wrote doesn't compiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible in F#.  See [How do I translate a `where T : U` generic type parameter constraint from C# to F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173283/how-do-i-translate-this-c-code-with-generic-type-constraints-to-f) and http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/10534.aspx.

Answer (score 6):

You can't write a type-safe function for this. You could however, use the [`upcast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233220.aspx#sectionToggle2) operator instead of your function.

Answer (score 3):

This is compiler restriction. Right type of the constraint 'a :> 'b must be of non generic type.