# How to define compile-time type casting operators in F#?

Tags: f#, casting, operators, compile-time

Given:

```
let ab = ArgumentBlockSettingStore()
let a  = ab :> ISettingStore
```

Is there a way to define a prefix operator `(~~)` so that

```
let ab, a = ~~ArgumentBlockSettingStore() : _ * ISettingStore
```

becomes possible?

Comment: looks like I hit some compiler restrictions as described in:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561663/rewrite-some-c-sharp-generic-code-into-f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're hitting the compiler restrictions that you mentioned in the comment - you can't write the `~~` operator in a fully generic and safe way meaning that it will only allow casting to an interface that the argument implements. You can define an operator that will cast to *any* other type, but that's less safe:

```
let inline (~~) (a:^T) : ^T * ^R = a, (box a) :?> ^R

let reader, (disposable:IDisposable) = ~~(new StreamReader("..."))
```

I used `inline`, because the operator is quite simple, but it works the same way with normal operators. This compiles even if you use `Random` in the type annotation for `disposable`, which is a bit unfortunate.

Comment: It is great to see that there's a way to do it albeit type-unsafe. Thanks a lot :) I guess I will not use it as I need such casting only in one place but I think it is a neat way to declare objects for use with all the various interfaces they may implement. Could also be extended to ~~~ for 1 type, 2 interfaces etc.